# Separate column from 2d-Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, csv

I am currently working on a Picture Indexing Tool.

By now, the Tool saves some Values (Filename, ID, description, etc.) from Textboxes in a .csv file (has to be csv). But I also need a function to load the data from a specified ID back to the Textboxes.

To be able to select a value, I thought of loading the .csv to a 2D-Array and then plotting the IDs to a ListBox where from I could select the csv-Line.

My problem now is how to load only the one specific ID-Column into the ListBox instead of the whole Array, and I really can't figure a way to seperate one Column from the 2d-Array.

The CSV looks like this:

`titel;A;0001;A0001;technik;maß;jahr;aufbewahrung;zustand;bemerkungen;False
titel2;B;0120;B0120;technik2;maße2;jahr2;aufbewahrung2;zustand2;bemerkungen2;False`

I would be glad if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0):

Besides a 2d-Array there is *a possibility* to use [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. You can define the field's width (if there is any) something like this:

```
 reader.SetFieldWidths(5, 21, 7, 20, -1)
```

and you may specify the delimiter as well:

```
 reader.Delimiters = New String() {","}
```

[Recommended Read](http://www.emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2010/05/Do-you-know-the-TextFieldParser.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. After struggling a bit with the TextFieldParser, I recognized that I used the Delimiter "," in all my attempts while using ";"s in the csv File. Now everything works fine.

Comment: glad to see you made it. :)